# Inductive filter vs capacitive filter: Which is better and gives less THD on the input side?

Tags: filter

I have a generalised statement that total harmonic distortion (THD) on input side for input supply current  is more for single phase diode rectifier with capacitive filter as compared to single phase rectifier with inductive filter. How is an inductive filter better than a capacitive filter in this context ?

Comment: Name (or link to) your rather misleading quote. I suspect I know what a more appropriate question is but until it's phrased better it's not worth answering.

Comment: An ideal capacitor cannot experience a voltage step except by conducting infinite current, whereas an ideal inductor can. As Vac rises above Vdc a capacitor input filter experiences the equivalent of close to a voltage step and a large current peak occurs with substantial diode and capacitor losses. Applying a voltage step to an inductor simply changes the rate of change of current - not the current itself. || A SLIGHTLY less generalised query and a circuit would help people to be sure of what you are asking. 
...

Comment: ... In simple cap in or cap only filters, adding a small series spreading R before the diode spreads the current peak and reduces losses overall.  | Note that if there was a current step rather than a voltage step then a cap filter would be superior to a inductor in filter for the equivalent reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify exactly what circuit you mean when you say *inductive filter* and *capacitive filter*.  Most likely your inductive filter has a capacitor in there too.  It's hard to imagine a single diode rectifier to make DC and not putting a cap across is somewhere.  If the inductor is therfore in addition to the cap, the additional filtering will additionally reduce high frequencies, which reduces the harmonics, and therfore the total distortion on the output.

Perhaps the statement is referring to THD of the current waveform on the input.  In that case a inductor in series will spread out the current over time instead of it being drawn in short spikes shortly around the input peaks.

Again, you need to specify more clearly what you are asking about to get a more accurate answer.